# Javascript call function from included script issue

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in Javascript, I recently added a tracker to my website which give me a javascript snippet to include in my website.

The tracking works well but I wanna know if I can get the information from this included script:

```
(function(c, d, a, e) {
    if (c[d]) {
        var f = function() {
            if (a.gifPostbackUrl) return a.gifPostbackUrl;
            e.error("Cannot retrieve click ID. Please, check your offer set up.")
        };
        c[d].registerConversion = function(b) {
            e.warn("Deprecated. You can now use getClickID method to retrieve Click ID and logConversion method to fire conversion postback");
            b(a.clickId)
        };
        c[d].getClickID = function() {
            return a.clickId
        };
        c[d].getTokens = function() {
            return a.offerUrlParameters || {}
        };
        c[d].getConversionPostbackPixelURL = function() {
            return f()
        };
        c[d].logConversion = function(b, c, d) {
            var a = f();
            a && (b && (a += "&payout=" + b), c && (a += "&txid=" + c), d && (a += "&et=" + d), b = document.createElement("img"), b.src = a, b.width = 1, b.height = 1, document.body.appendChild(b))
        };
        c[d].state.callbackQueue.forEach(function(b) {
            return b(a.clickId)
        })
    }
})
(window, "dtpCallback", {
    "clickId": "IDOFCLICK",
    "campaignId": "CAMPAIGNID",
    "gifPostbackUrl": "https://multioned-bactempt.icu/conversion.gif?cid=IDOFCLICK&caid=CAMPAIGNID",
    "offerUrlParameters": {}
}, console);
```

Please note that campaignID and clickId are variable.

I want to know if it's possible to use javascript code after including this tracking code to get CLICK ID and Campaign ID.

I tried to call function getClickID but it returns as undefined. Can anyone give me a road to follow or help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: I may be missing something, but if you are including that code yourself, why not change it to extract `options = { "clickId": "IDOFCLICK", "campaignId": "CAMPAIGNID", "gifPostbackUrl": "https://multioned-bactempt.icu/conversion.gif?cid=IDOFCLICK&caid=CAMPAIGNID", "offerUrlParameters": {} }`? This will allow you to then check `options.clickId` or `options.campaignId`. You can still pass the object in as `(function(c, d, a, e) { /*...*/ }) (window, "dtpCallback", options, console);`

Comment: @VLAZ I am not including that code myself, it's included as link from the tracker, but this is the response of the link !

Comment: The script passes a self invoking function. You cannot access any part of it.

Comment: @TimonNetherlands In fact I've been able to get it using this : dtpCallback.getClickID();

Answer (score 1):

In fact I've been able to get it using this:

```
dtpCallback.getClickID();
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Would you please share complete working code. The example from very bottom of this link does not seems to be working. https://doc.voluum.com/en/dtp_customziations.html

Comment: dtpCallback.getClickID(); This code works after some time. But I do not want to use setTimeout for that, I wanna use the callback functions.